# How do you compare two HWND pointers?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is it possible to do

```
if(HWND1 == HWND2)
```

or is there a function that I need to use to see if two hwnd point to the same window?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A HWND is just a long value, so yes you can compare them that way.

Answer (score 5):

Depends how stale your data is. Windows re-uses hwnds (eventually), so there's no *guarantee* that 1005A is both a valid window and the window you expected, it might be another window that re-used 1005A.